# Script executed as super user

Tags: php, admin, root

How can I tell from within my PHP script if it is executed with super user rights?

If it isn't called like `sudo php script.php` I can throw an error

```
if (!is_sudo()) {
  die('Please execute with sudo');
}
```

I am sure there's a simple way to check, but I just didn't found it yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [posix_getuid()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getuid.php) (0 is `root`):

```
if (posix_getuid() != 0) {
    die('Please execute with sudo');
}
```

as @Dave Random suggested:

```
function is_sudo () {
    return posix_getuid() === 0;
}
```

Comment: +1, and for the hell of it: `function is_sudo () { return posix_getuid() === 0; }`